# Checking 2 files exist with os.path.isfile and 'and' statement

Tags: python

I was working through a problem last night, and came across some Redhat 6 Linux shell code with some embedded python code being used to append one file to another.  I encountered a file not found error.  As this is production code, I isolated and checked the logic of this python statement:

```
if os.path.isfile(str(sys.argv[1]) and str(sys.argv[2])):
  [do the append stuff]
else:
  print("Error: Input file(s) do not exist")
```

In other languages I would expect to iterate os.path.isfile twice...

I tested this with two arbitrary files "file1" and "file2" and found some odd behaviour.

`append.py "file1" "file2"` triggers append code as expected

`append.py "file1" "file2x"` triggers Error message as expected

`append.py "file1x" "file2x"` triggers Error message as expected

`append.py "file1x" "file2"` triggers append code - Not expected!

I was not expecting this last; and probably explains my production issue.

I tried something like this (sorry from memory, as cannot copy paste from secure environment):

```
if (os.path.isfile(str(sys.argv[1])) and os.path.isfile(str(sys.argv[2]))):
```

but got the same result..so I am now thinking it is something else.

why is first operand being evaluated incorrectly as being present?

Comment: can you describe what are `file1`/`file1x`/etc.?

Comment: `foo and bar` evaluates to `bar` unless `foo` is false-y, in which case it evaluates to `foo`. Given that you're always passing two arguments, and a non-empty string is truth-y, you're always only checking the second file.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, sorry I wasn't clear.  file1 and file2 are just files I created for testing. file1x and file2x are just deliberately not valid files, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the expression

```
os.path.isfile(str(sys.argv[1]) and str(sys.argv[2]))
```

where the first argument is `"file1x"` and the second is `"file2"` reduces to

```
os.path.isfile(str("file1x") and str("file2"))
```

which reduces to

```
os.path.isfile("file2")
```

which is

```
True
```

Remember that

```
x and y
```

evaluates to `y` if `x` is truthy!

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

> x and y --> if x is false, then x, else y

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the code checks if `file1` exists or, if it's empty, falls back to checking whether `file2` exists. `a and b` returns `a` if it is true, otherwise returns `b`.

The elements of `sys.argv` are strings by definition, so the `str()` invocations are a superfluous no-op.

If you want to check whether both files exist, the updated code you attempted should work. Alternatively, you could do something like

```
if all(os.file.isfile(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]):
    print("all these exist and are regular files: {0}".format(sys.argv[1:]))
```

which has the attractive additional feature that it doesn't hard-code the expected number of arguments.